# PyQT5 Second window wont close on button press

Tags: python, pyqt5

So Im working on an inventory management system for a project. I currently have two windows and a database. When I open the second window I have two buttons, one that will eventually save the data into the database and one to cancel the entry. (yes i know you can just press the X) I want the second window to close when i press cancel, but no matter what tutorial i've tried no matter what form of self.close() or other types, ive edited the UI file, ive done it in my main, i just cannot seem to get it to recognize that im pressing the button, when i do get it to recognize its by using `self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(lambda: closeit(self))`

this is in the windows class and then i have

```
def closeit(self):
    print("clicked")
```

outside all classes and it will print clicked in the console but as soon as i change it to

```
self.close()
```

then the program screams that the UI_AddRecord has no attribute close and i cant close the window.

I am editing this in a new file from two UI Files. Heres the main.py code relating to what im trying to do.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("T6_Asset_Management.ui", self)
        self.niprTable.setColumnWidth(5, 175)
        self.loaddata()
        self.addNewItem.clicked.connect(self.addNewRecord)

    def addNewRecord(self):
        self.Add_New_Record = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_AddRecord()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.Add_New_Record)
        self.Add_New_Record.show()


class Add_New_Record(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_AddRecord):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Add_New_Record, self).__init__()
        loadUi("Add_New_Record.ui", self)
        self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

Pyuic file for the second window:

```
class Ui_AddRecord(object):
    def setupUi(self, AddRecord):
        AddRecord.setObjectName("AddRecord")
        AddRecord.resize(1098, 575)
        self.saveButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(AddRecord)
        self.saveButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 500, 91, 31))
        self.saveButton.setObjectName("saveButton")
        self.cancelButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(AddRecord)
        self.cancelButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(770, 500, 91, 31))
        self.cancelButton.setObjectName("cancelButton")
        self.retranslateUi(AddRecord)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AddRecord)

    def retranslateUi(self, AddRecord):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        AddRecord.setWindowTitle(_translate("AddRecord", "Add New Record"))
        self.saveButton.setText(_translate("AddRecord", "Save"))
        self.cancelButton.setText(_translate("AddRecord", "Cancel"))
```

Main Window Code The button that opens the new window is the add record button.

```
  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1106, 600)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../OneDrive/Pictures/MTC_Logo-removebg-preview-removebg-preview.bmp"),
                       QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.addNewItem = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.addNewItem.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 0, 91, 23))
        self.addNewItem.setObjectName("addNewItem")
        self.deleteSelected = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.deleteSelected.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 0, 91, 23))
        self.deleteSelected.setObjectName("deleteSelected")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1106, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFiles = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFiles.setObjectName("menuFiles")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionSave_To_Database = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave_To_Database.setObjectName("actionSave_To_Database")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionExport = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExport.setObjectName("actionExport")
        self.menuFiles.addAction(self.actionSave_To_Database)
        self.menuFiles.addAction(self.actionExport)
        self.menuFiles.addSeparator()
        self.menuFiles.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFiles.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "T6 Asset Management"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.close)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro I'm afraid that the OP is trying to edit the pyuic file and call`self.close` from there.

Comment: @MatthewVanDruff You're not trying to edit the file generated by pyuic, are you? Also, why are you inheriting from `Ui_AddRecord` and then call `loadUi`? And why don't you use *that* class, instead of creating `Ui_AddRecord` in `addNewRecord`?

Comment: lol not editing the pyuic file ;) I watched the video you sent me yesterday, i have a main.py that im writing code in and inheriting like the documentation says :). For the last question, the button wont open the new window if its not in the main window class.

Comment: @MatthewVanDruff Sorry, I can't keep track of all users :-) But, if you get a "UI_AddRecord has no attribute close", that can only mean that there's still something wrong in your implementation (maybe you didn't properly rewrite the pyuic generated files?): in the code above there's absolutely no mention to `closeit`, so I can only assume it's still in the UI class. You didn't try to directly *subclass* it, did you? About your last point, sorry but I really don't understand what you mean. You either use multiple inheritance with the Qt and UI classes, or you use `loadUi`. Not both.

Comment: @musicamante I know that, but it's still the correct solution. I correctly surmised there was little point in attempting to second guess what the OP had been actually trying to do ;-)

Comment: @musicamante the closeit function was in there Sorry the code wasnt fully updated, because i kept trying tons of different things to get it to work but it just doesnt wanna work for me, if i go into the generated pyuic file and do the lambda in the button code and put the closeit function outside of the main class it will print a message with the print command but when i switch it to .close it starts throwing errors, would you be willing to help me out and help me understand what im doing wrong? ive tried so many different topics and different code forms and i just cant get it to work :(

Comment: @ekhumoro your correct in the usage but unfortunately its not working for me and thats what im here to ask lol I know what code needs to be used i just cant figure out why when i use it im getting the error.

Comment: @MatthewVanDruff so what is the *actual* code? Where is `closeit`? How is it connected? If you get an error, we need to see the code that *reproduces* it.

Comment: @MatthewVanDruff It's pointless discussing this any further unless you provide a proper [mre].

Comment: heres the full code that does nothing
https://pastebin.com/fMWWqbga

This one uses self.close also does nothing
https://pastebin.com/v2XS4dFk

Comment: @ekhumoro
Posted the two main versions of the code i tried to get it to work

Comment: @MatthewVanDruff But it's clearly *not* the full code, since the `Ui_AddRecord` class and ui files are missing (so nobody else can test your code). Also, posting off-site links is not appropriate. Please therefore *edit your question* and provide a proper [mre].

Comment: @MatthewVanDruff The code works fine for me if I delete the line `loadUi("Add_New_Record.ui", self)` (which makes no sense, as pointed out above) and replace it with the standard `self.setupUi(self)`. Of course, the cancel button works just fine as well and closes the window as expected. However, I doubt whether this is any real use to you, since the code you've posted still isn't really a [mre]. Because of that, I'm not going to respond to any further comments until you've properly addressed this issue.

Comment: @ekhumoro tried your suggestion and still getting same result added the code from all three files minus the parts that have nothing to do with the issue, retested to ensure it still ends up with same result and button still not working.

Comment: @ekhumoro any ideas

Comment: @MatthewVanDruff See my previous comment.

Comment: @ekhumoro yeah i updated it with all pertinent code im not sure what more i can give you this is everything necessary to test it???????????????